# xslt using variables for expression

Tags: xml, variables, xslt

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="adlength" select="35"/>
<xsl:for-each select="/*/locations/location">
<xsl:variable name="currentadlength" select="position()"/>
<xsl:if test="$currentadlength < $adlength">
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

My issue is with this line of code:

```
<xsl:if test="$currentadlength < $adlength">
```

What I need is to enter the `if` stage if the `currentadlength` is less than `adlength`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/locations/location[position() &lt; 35]">
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

?

Comment: This is a great answer. Can you also provide explanation of using variables just so i know

Comment: Like `<xsl:for-each select="*/locations/location[position() &lt; $adlength]">`?

Comment: No i mean as my original question. I just want to understand this,

Comment: You can't have `<` in an attribute value in XML document, that's all. Use `&lt;` and all is well.